# How do I get Anaconda3 to see Python 2.7 after installing it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

So, I set up Anaconda(3) on my Windows 8 computer, it worked without problems. Now, I also need an installation of Python 2, so I created an appropriate additional environment. Sadly, after activating that environment, the python interpreter it sees stays the same. What am I doing wrong?
(Shortened) console output:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27:

<snip>
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _license:           1.1-py27_0
    anaconda:           2.1.0-np19py27_0
<snip>
    python:             2.7.8-0
<snip>
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

menuinst-1.0.4 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 239.25 kB/s
Fetching packages ...
_license-1.1-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 432.62 kB/s
anaconda-2.1.0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 150.62 kB/s
<snip>
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate py27
#

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>activate py27
Activating environment "py27"...

[py27] C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
<why isn't python 2.7.8 visible here??>
```

Doing `echo %PATH%` before and after activation gives this output

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>activate py27
Activating environment "py27"...

[py27] C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts;C:
\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\S
ystem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program File
s (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts

[py27] C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
```

This looks correct. Additionally, the `python.exe` in `\envs\py27\python.exe` *is* a 2.7.8 Python!

Comment: What does `echo %PATH%` look like before and after the `activate` call?

Comment: @filmor: I added the relevant output - the py27 env gets prepended to PATH, which looks correct to me.

Comment: Could this be because the above happens in an Anaconda prompt (which gets installed in the "start menu"), not a "regular" shell?

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you're still in the Anaconda3 directory and . takes precedence over PATH on Windows. cd somewhere else and try it again.

Comment: @filmor indeed, that's it! Please post this as a solution so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows the current path takes precedence over the `PATH` variable when accessing binaries. Thus, since you are still in the `Anaconda3` directory containing `python.exe`, `cmd` will choose that one instead of looking it up via the `PATH` which would have returned the Python 2.7 executable. `cd` to a different path and you are fine.